# Current through MOSFET of ideal forward converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, ltspice, waveform

I am asked to sketch the current through the MOSFET of an ideal forward converter. I simulated a forward converter in LTspice and found that when the MOSFET was on, the MOSFET current and input current are identical. When the switch is off, no current flows through the MOSFET.

[image]

So a waveform would look like this: -

[image]

However, my instructor insisted in his lecture that it should be \$\frac{I_{in}}{D}\$, so the waveform would be: -

[image]

I don't see how the current through the MOSFET could be dependent on the duty cycle. I asked him if he could elaborate but he couldn't... Which one is correct waveform?

Comment: Why have you drawn them with flat tops?

Comment: @Andyaka In my power electronics course we assume everything ideal, so no magnetization winding. Also assume that capacitances and inductor are infinitely big so no ripple.

Answer (score 1):

For a truly *ideal* forward converter, you need to set your transformer inductance to near infinity (but high mH to H range is probably good enough) and same for your output inductor. To a lesser extent, the output capacitor needs to be very large too. With everything but duty cycle and output load being infinity, Id will be a flat line as in your last image.

In practice, this is a tradeoff as with everything else in SMPS design. High inductance will make your primary current flatter at the top and save some MOSFET losses but drives up the cost and size for your magnetics. So you choose a suitable value to balance the two. Transformer too large? Trade off some inductance and suffer a little bit higher RMS current on the primary. MOSFET overheating but transformer running cool as a cucumber? Go with thinner wire and increase the inductance to move some losses from the MOSFET to the transformer.

Comment: Thanks winny, using mH and mF instead of uF made the waveform look "ideal". However, what I'm concerned about is if the MOSFET current is \$\frac{I_{in}}{D}\$. I can't see why it should be that.

Comment: For a given output voltage, the turns ratio have changed for a change in D, so it's no longer apples to apples due to new transformer. For a given turns ratio, output voltage (and current) will vary linearly with D as long as you are in CCM. Your instructor hid that for you and simplified the formula, which confuses things. Output voltage in CCM will be Vin x D x Ns/Np = Vout.

Comment: I don't think I'm following. I'm not looking at the output at all right now. I'm only looking at the current through the MOSFET (which is the same as current through L2). Does this current depend on the duty cycle? Because LTspice says the complete opposite.

Comment: I can see why. If you keep Vin constant, transformer ratio constant, ignore output voltage and straight constant resistive load, and just vary D, Id will be linear with D. This is opposite of what your instructor showed. Please simulate it.